# Import a .mdb to SQLServer via Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

**Context**

We need to import a .mdb archive to our local database so that we can manipulate all the DATA.

**DATA**

that .mdb file Always have the same amount of tables (58)  and the same table structure,
those tables may have 109.000 to 10million entries

**Actual situation**

Now we have a python program that do the migration (called Migrathon) that is actually old and pretty damn slow, it takes more than 10 hours to import 16.000 entries to our local data base so here they wanted to change it.

**What i have to do**

First of all i work for ppl that use GeneXus Evo1, this tool can execute SP from a datasource , so what i need or what i want to do is a Procedure that can Take from the .mdb source an migrate every table that is into that file to a local DataBase where i manipulate everything as i please

**My question**

Is there any chance of doing it? its SQLServer2008 and the Access Files are from AC2003,
the data structure as i said before are always the same structure, same tables, same name the only diference are the amount of entries, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and OLEDB driver into a t-sql procedure like this :

```
SELECT * INTO #yourWorkTable FROM OPENDATASOURCE (‘Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0′, ‘Data Source=\\server-name\mdbs\test.mdb’)…[tableName]
```

With this query you got everything you need; just add some programming to iterate through tables and you are done

Comment: It worked perfectly, i added this
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a simple SSIS package, or does it have to be done via SProc?  It would seem like that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Ye it can be done that way, the problem is that it has to be under a GeneXus app and that mean an SP

Comment: GeneXus Evo 1 not longer support access files, as far as i know and also they just dump their WIN platform just to focus on WEB and MOBILE so im trying hard with what i have XD